# static readonly field causes StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, stack-overflow

In ASP.NET website I have `static readonly XGeoPhone provider = new XGeoPhone();`. Inside of `XGeoPhone` class I have `static readonly XPhoneInfo[] phoneInfo = new[] { new XPhoneInfo(......), ... 250000 more objects ... }`. When I run this on developer machine or real server — it crashes at `new XGeoPhone()` with `StackOverflowException`. I do not quite understand it tries to create this giant array on stack, not heap? What is going on?

UPDATE: Simplest version that will crash:

```
public partial class XGeoPhone
{
    public XPhoneInfo GetInfo(long phone)
    {
        return
            phoneInfos.
            FirstOrDefault(pi =>
                pi.Start <= phone &&
                phone <= pi.End);
    }

    static readonly XPhoneInfo[] phoneInfos = new[]
    {
        new XPhoneInfo(2000000000, 2099999999, XCountryId.EG, null, null),
        new XPhoneInfo(2120000000, 2129999999, XCountryId.MA, null, null),
        new XPhoneInfo(2130000000, 2139999999, XCountryId.DZ, null, null),
        new XPhoneInfo(2160000000, 2169999999, XCountryId.TN, null, null),
        new XPhoneInfo(2180000000, 2189999999, XCountryId.LY, null, null),
        .........
    }
}

public class XPhoneInfo
{
    public XPhoneInfo(long start, long end, XCountryId? country, string region, string provider)
    {
        this.Start = start;
        this.End = end;
        this.Country = country;
        this.Region = region;
        this.Provider = provider;
    }

    public long Start { get; private set; }
    public long End { get; private set; }
    public XCountryId? Country { get; private set; }
    public string Region { get; private set; }
    public string Provider { get; private set; }
}

class Program
{
    static readonly XGeoPhone g = new XGeoPhone();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var v = g.GetInfo(79054567890);
    }
}
```

Comment: likely you have a recursive construction

Comment: `250000` objects added manually by code? **CODE SMELL**

Comment: `....250000 more objects....` that's smells orribly!

Comment: Perhaps you could share the code (stripping out almost all the objects) so we can see what's happening.

Comment: @buffjape I added the code.

Comment: try making `XPhoneInfo` a `struct`, `struct`s have much different semantics and unless you need to edit them are probably the better way to do this. Although the best way would be an external data store.

Comment: @Mgetz `struct` didn't help me, it crashes anyway

Comment: @Denis it was worth a try, it's crashing because it has to load the data into the stack frame all at once. I was hoping that by using `struct`s it could instead just move the data into a read only data segment and then just map it in

Answer (score -1):

Okay, I found the workaround — I can create a thread and specify the stack size in a thread’s constructor, like described [here](http://content.atalasoft.com/h/i/58213648-increasing-the-size-of-your-stack-net-memory-management-part-3). It works. But I decided to move that big array to csv file.